# white page when i click on system-configuration

Tags: configuration, magento-1

I have added a new theme, but when i clik the system-configuration, showt a white page. with this error.
(Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463)

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: is any error log file generated?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that all the files are installed properly. toOptionArray is a method from object that populates drop-down options. Here the object value seems to be null, which usually happens when declaration file is either missing or not readable.

Comment: in the beginning I had installed him in localhost and there have no problem, but in the online shop that gives some problems. I mustto say when I switch maintenance extension gives the same problems as much in the front and backend of magento, only when I changed the value  into the extesion i can login.

Answer (score 0):

No. I see the upper error  when I add this code (ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');) to index.php. I forget to indicate that in line 463.

(Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463)